# MVC5 Bundler being too greedy?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Here is my script folder's jquery prefixed scripts

[image: All jQuery prefixed Scripts]

Why (when i build for release) is my 90.4KB **minified** file giving a 156K output?
[image: fiddler]
When i inspect the file it is **minified**, is it possible its combining more than one file?

I am using the MVC5 beta files so im not sure if the wildcard i am using is still correct?

Comment: Have you used release configuration? In debug configuration it may use non-minified jquery.

Comment: yes release mode and debug false in the web.config, i did mention above that its minified. cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you run with debug=true, by default the bundle's contents will be enumerated as individual links and you can see approximately what its trying to include.  It will differ slightly as it will choose .min.js over plain .js.